# How to structure a grid with string references to objects

Tags: java, oop

I'm working on a problem that needs me to distribute resources on a grid like this:

```
|A|B|C
|X|C|X
|A|X|X
```

I'm working out the best solution to my problem through a means of combined search algorithms. Because of the algorithms, it's easier to handle String values in the grid. However, when the initial grid is settled I need to access some properties. Say A is for apples, then I might need to access the size of an Apple.

So I made a class fruits now, and I'm adding the fruits I need on initialization. Since fruits need to be added in runtime as well it can't be an enumerate, something I tried first.

Since the solution sometimes takes as much as 10000+ tries, I figured checking Strings against each other is faster then making all those Strings into objects isn't it?

Now I can't get my head around how to do this. Basically I want to be able to define my fruits in one place and simply say in the grid: "This a is an apple".

EDIT:
Maybe it's indeed more of a basic OOP question. 
How do I make it possible for users to define new types of objects, say new sorts of fruit, from within the program?

Comment: What are the constraints on the distribution? It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

String is an object as well, it uses fields and methods just like your custom object would do. Then why not to write your custom object?

If the fruit types are "registered" at runtime, then put `int id`, representing a kind of fruit, into your Fruit object, beside properties like `double size`, and also use some separate global `Map<int, String>`, outside `Fruit` of course, which assigns names or any other description to each id. You might even wrap that map into some "fruit register" class, which assigns subsequent integers to each new `id` with `int newFruitType(String description)`, writes a respective entry to the map discussed and returns the newly created `id`.

In order to avoid duplicates, you might use an "index" `Map<String, int>`, which would store all ids and descriptions put inside `Map<int, String>`, but the key would be the description this time. The register class would then just check the index for the uniqueness of each new fruit type requested, before putting that type to the map. If the fruit types are added through UI, then, to help the user, you might also display the sorted contents of the index in the respective add form. To keep the index contents sorted, you might store it in some `SortedMap<String, int>`.

Comment: I was indeed thinking of using some sort of Map for this. But how would that work if someone had a page in the UI in which they can define new types of fruit?